# Does the word "do" have a meaning of "study"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I've already done the background on the woman.

It seems that the word *do* here has the same meaning with *study* or *investigate*. Is that right? Can you give me some more examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does not look normal to my eyes! *I've already backgrounded the woman.* still makes sense to me. OR, *I'm done with her background (study?).*

Comment: @MaulikV - There are actually at least two valid interpretations of this sentence; nohat has explained one, and Nitika has offered another. On the other hand, I would **not** say, "I've already backgrounded the woman," although English is flexible enough that _background_ could be converted into a verb like that and people would understand what you are saying. It would be a non-standard usage of the word, but that sort of thing isn't at all without precedent – just think about how _Google_ has been made into a verb in the past few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, "background" is shortened form for "background check" or "background investigation". To "do the background" would be to "do (perform) the background check or background investigation".

Answer (score 2):

The given example could convey a different meaning. What if you're using software like Photoshop, and you've manually designed a graphical background for a woman's picture or image?

So, the sentence could be talking about an investigation, but it could also be talking about some kind of graphics work. Without further context, there's no way to tell for sure what the verb *done* really means.

Comment: Could I please know who downvoted this, and reason behind the same? I would also want to know if there is a way of identifying the upvoter or downvoter by myself?

Comment: Voting is anonymous, so there's no way to tell who downvoted. As for why, I can only guess (because it wasn't my downvote), but I'm guessing that someone thinks the sentence means what the O.P. thinks it means, but you've said it means something different. I've changed the wording a little bit; I hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: Thanks :) both for the edit and striking off the downvote.

Comment: agreed with response -- the word background could  mean what the answer says -- I think downvoter should retract.

Comment: Nitika - just to be clear, I don't have the power to "strike off" downvotes, but I am able to upvote when I think someone has made an excellent point :^)

Comment: Oh, I get it :) thanks. The doubts on my part exist because I am a new member to this website.